# Google Maps API get longitude and latitude clicking on the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build a really useful web service and want to simplify the place choose using google maps. Is there any possibility to get longitude and latitude and write it down to input tags just by clicking on the map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how i would do this:

```
var map = ...;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    $('input.latitude').val(event.latLng.lat());
    $('input.longitude').val(event.latLng.lng());
});
```

Comment: If that worked for you, don't hesitate to upvote my answer, and mark your question as answered

Comment: I didn't forget but it allows me to mark as answerd when just some time comes.

Comment: The LatLng object does not have methods called getLatitude() and getLongitude(). Instead it has lat() and lng() (I edited the reply) - see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng